# Download PDF from server to clients machine

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anybody help me in downloading PDF from server/FTP to Clients machine to particular path using javascript / JQuery.

I was trying to do it in C#. But its not possible in C#, because when I try to find a path, it finds it on server machine.

Thanx in Advance.

Comment: Hi, Dipali - Can you please provide at-list some work (code) what you done and what you try ? Coz Its easy to us for find solution of your question

Comment: @ShivamPandya I dont have any code right now. I did not find it.

Comment: Are the pdf and your jquery code on same domain ? You can find path via jquery but it don't work on cross domain. And are you trying to download from server to client. right ? or client click on link and pdf will download

Comment: Yes, pdf and jquery is on same domain. On client click on link pdf should get downloaded in the provided path.

Comment: So basically you want that client download pdf via jquery, not clasic HTML, right ?

Comment: Yes right. I want pdf from server via javascript/jquery.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you might be want,

Create Button with class/ID

```
    <input type = "button" class = "cssbuttongo" value = "Download PDF" >
```

**Jquery**

```
jQuery('.cssbuttongo').click( function (e) {
  var url = location.protocol + "//" + location.host + "/yourfile.extention"; // Change yourfile.extention to your pdf download path
  window.location.href = "#!"; // Add variable URL Here
  alert(url);
});
```

[**Fiddle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/tutorialdrive/9x0hzq7n/)

Comment: what will be 'location.protocol' and "#!" ?

Comment: location.protocol get http or https from url, location.host get full domain name and #! would replace by your path (without domain name. for example /source/pdf/sample.pdf)
so full path is like http://yourdomain.com/source/pdf/sample.pdf

Comment: I want to download pdf in D: drive. So will it like 'D:\\PDF\\sample.pdf' ?

Comment: did you mean that server decide where to download pdf on client's machine ?

Comment: yes. I want to download pdf from server to users machine in specified path

Comment: No, its not possible, Browser/ Server can not handle client machine. It is a security reason. Each person has to set their download preferences for themselves. Choosing a download directory for them would be a client-side operation and cannot be done with JavaScript  or jQuery.

Comment: but javascript runs client side. I have already done a code which saves images of clients machine from one location to another

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63007/discussion-between-shivam-pandya-and-dipali-wagh).